# Angular set disabled option selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Have the next selector:

```
<select
      ng-model="vm.selectedUserState"
      ng-options="u as u.Group disable when u.Obsolete for u in vm.UserStates">
</select>
```

when page is loaded and current status code disabled (Obsolete is true), i see empty selection, how i can fix this (pre-select an appropriate option even when an item is disabled)

Comment: so you can write?    `u as u.Group for u in vm.UserStates track by u.Obsolete=false`

Comment: or like this:  `<select
      ng-model="vm.selectedUserState"
      ng-options="u as u.Group for u in vm.UserStates" ng-if="u.Obsolete">
</select>`

Comment: @Saahon the code you've provided not work (using the second listing select does not appear at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-model` is probably undefined on load, if you want an initial selected item set your `ng-model` in your controller

```
vm.selectedUserState = vm.UserStates[selectionKeyName]
```

---

**update:**
Looking at the Angular source I don't think it's possible:

```
if (option && !option.disabled) { //Skips if it's disabled <----
  if (selectElement[0].value !== option.selectValue) {
    removeUnknownOption();
    removeEmptyOption();

    selectElement[0].value = option.selectValue;
    option.element.selected = true;
    option.element.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  }
} else {
  if (value === null || providedEmptyOption) {
    removeUnknownOption();
    renderEmptyOption();
  } else {
    removeEmptyOption();
    renderUnknownOption();
  }
}
```

Comment: no, im sure vm completely defined (if vm.selectedUserState is not obsolete (no disabled) all works properly)

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding an addition check

```
<select
      ng-model="vm.selectedUserState"
      ng-options="u as u.Group disable when (u.Obsolete && vm.selectedUserState.Code !== u.Code) for u in vm.UserStates">
</select>
```